# Javascript clock, changing the time

Tags: javascript, click, raphael, clock

I am building a clock in javaScript using the Raphael library, but i can't seem to get it to change the hours permanently when i click on my arrows, it changes the time by one hour, but then a second later will change back to the correct time that it currently is.

```
     function startTime(){
     var today = new Date();
     var h = today.getHours();
     var m = today.getMinutes();
     var s = today.getSeconds();

     var ny_h = today.getHours()-5;
     var hk_h = today.getHours()+8;
     var jh_h = today.getHours()+2;

     var multiplier = 0;

     m = checkTime(m);
     s = checkTime(s);
     h = checkTime(h);

seconds.animate({transform: [ 'r',((s*6)-180),200,200]});
minute.animate({transform: [ 'r',((m*6)-180),200,200]});
hour.animate({transform: [ 'r',(((h+multiplier)*30)-180),200,200]});

change.click(function(){
    var arrow1 = paper.path(up).attr({fill:"black"});
    var arrow2 = paper.path(down).attr({fill:"black"});
    arrow1.click(function(){
        multiplier+=1;
      //var h = today.getHours()+1;
});

setTimeout(function(){startTime()},1000);

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}   

}

startTime(); //Function call that starts the startTime function.
```

I have tried to plus one hour onto the hour variable when the arrow is clicked but that changes back after a second. So I also tried to add a variable called multiplier and change that everytime I click the arrow, subsequently changing the time, but I can't seem to access the multiplier variable inside my click function. I don't know why that is and would really appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: each time you call startTime, which is ever second, you set multiplier to zero. So updating multipler in a nested click handler only lasts a short time... the definition of multipler or any other lasting time correction needs to be more global.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `startTime` defines time correction variables, displays time and schedules itself to be called again in a second.

A function to show time, `showTime` needs to be included separately if correction variables, defined within `startTime`, are to be preserved without being redefined each time `showTime` is called.

A timeout call started within `showTime` would then look like `setTimeout( showTime, 1000);`.

Alternatively you could use `setInterval( showTime, 1000);` as an ongoing interval timer started from within the `startTime` outer function;

Comment: This is the correct answer (up voted). Yet, since I had already started writing an answer I posted mine as well.

Answer (score 0):

This simple example should get your stated. Notice that the multiplier variable is moved outside of the function so that it retains its value. The setTime() was replaced with setInterval().  Now all you need to do is insert your Raphaël code in the updateClock() function.

**Run the snippet to see it work**

```js
var multiplier = 0;

// click handler     
function setHour(n) {
  multiplier += n;
  updateClock();
}

// update UI
function updateClock() {
  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(today.getHours() + multiplier);
  document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = today.toLocaleTimeString();


  // insert your Raphaël code to update the clock here


}


// initialize 
updateClock();
window.setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
```

```css
.container a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 1.2em;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
#clock {
  font-size: 23px;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="setHour(1)">▲</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="setHour(-1)">▼</a>
  <span id="clock"></span>
</div>
```